# Integration with complex numbers

Tags: integration

I know that you can integrate

$$\int e^{-x}\cos(x)dx$$

by parts, but I would like to know how you can use complex variables instead.

Comment: Use Euler's formula to express $\cos x$ in terms of complex exponentials.

Comment: Re integration by parts -- is that possible for this integral? I don't see how that would work.

Comment: @Ben I think it is possible to integrate this by parts. In general it is possible to integrate $\int e^{ax} \cos bx \mathrm d x$ by parts. The same is true when $\cos bx$ is replaced by $\sin bx$.

Answer (score 8):

**Euler's form of a complex Number:**

$$e^{i x}=\cos x+i \sin x$$

And, note that, as $\sin (-x)= -\sin x$ and $\cos (-x) = \cos x$, we have that, $$e^{-i x}=\cos x-i \sin x$$

This together gives you, $$\cos x = \dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

Note: $\Re$ stands for the real part of a complex number and $\Im$ for its imaginary part.

**Method 1:**

$$\begin{align*}\int e^{-x}\cos x~~ \mathrm d x &= \Re\left(\int e^{-x}e^{ix} \mathrm dx\right)\\&=\Re\left(\int e^{x(i-1)} \mathrm d x\right) \\&=\Re\left(\dfrac{e^{x(i-1)}}{i-1}\right)\\&=e^{-x}\cdot\Re\left(\dfrac{\cos x+ i \sin x}{-1+i}\right) \\&= e^{-x} \cdot\dfrac{\sin x-\cos x}{2}\end{align*} $$

**Method 2:**(Ben's Comment)

$$\begin{align*} \int e^{-x} \cos x ~\mathrm dx&=\int e^{-x} \cdot \dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2} \mathrm dx\\&=\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \int (e^{ix-x}+e^{-ix-x}) \mathrm d x\\&=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\dfrac{e^{x(i-1)}}{i-1}+\dfrac{e^{x(-1-i)}}{-i-1}\right)\end{align*}$$

Leaving the simplifications to you, you will see that the answer still turns out to be the same.

Comment: Looks fine, except that the factor of 1/2 appears one line too early. As an alternative to using the real part, one can write $\cos x$ as $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$.

Comment: @Ben I have added your suggestion as well. Thank You!